# Understanding Zorn's lemma xx

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**1)** In the Keith Condrad's [notes says](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/zorn1.pdf) **Theorem 1.1 (Zorn’s lemma).** Let $S$ be a partially ordered set. If every totally ordered subset of $S$ has an upper bound, then $S$ contains a maximal element.

**2)** MathWorld [says](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZornsLemma.html) If $S$ is any nonempty partially ordered set in which every *chain* has an upper bound, then $S$ has a maximal element.

**My question is**: What is the differences between 1) and 2)? Condrad don't use *chain* in the notes.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, there is no difference.

A *chain* is just a totally ordered subset. And since the empty set is a chain, its upper bound automatically makes $S$ non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

In this context, a "chain" in a partial order means exactly a totally ordered subset.